# How can we extract email from memory file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract email from memory(RAM) dump file. The below method works only for text files:

```
def checkmail():
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=50000) as f:
        #for line in f:
             var=f.read()
             value1=var.decode('utf-8','ignore')
             pattern='[^,;\s]+@[^,;\s]+'
             value2=re.findall(pattern,value1)
                    
             convertedstring = value2 [::-1]
             for i in convertedstring:
                 listbox_mail.insert("end", i)
    return
```

Comment: your loop does not make sense, you do `for line in f` but then on the next line you read in the whole file by doing `var = f.read()`

Comment: What file format exactly? A Windows `.dmp` file is not only a raw memory file. Also, in a RAM dump, the information may not be contiguous. Memory is handled in pages and you need to consider page borders. Part of the memory may have paged out, so you might not even find what you're looking for. All in all, dealing with memory dumps is a hard topic. Somehow I feel doing this sort of stuff does not match your programming skills.

Comment: Are you looking for emails or email addresses?

Comment: You can treat data in memory like it was a binary file by using [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) — so if you have working code that operates on a file, it should be easy to convert it.

Comment: The file format is .raw...And i'm looking for email addresses

Comment: I don't think `.raw` is well-defined. Sounds like the format used for the unprocessed images from some digital cameras?

Comment: It is a memory image format here. i.e, a collection of unprocessed data which i captured using DumpIt tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already scanning binary data. If you are only looking for single-byte ASCII-compatible text encodings, just don't decode, and look for `bytes` instead.

```py
import re

def checkmail():
    # Do this outside the loop, just once
    # use raw string and bytes, and a more constrained pattern
    pattern = re.compile(br'[-A-Za-z0-9+_.]+@[-A-Za-z0-9+]+(?:\.[-A-Za-z0-9+]+)+')
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=50000) as f:
        for line in f:
             # Bug fix; don't
             #var=f.read()
             # Also don't
             #value1=var.decode('utf-8','ignore')
             for match in pattern.findall(line):
                 # No idea what this does; assume it's correct
                 listbox_mail.insert("end", match.decode('ascii'))
    return
```

Properly speaking, your function should probably `return` or `yield` the matches, and let the caller decide what to do with them. The weird pesky apparently global variable `listbox_mail` looks like something to avoid.

The regex is ad hoc and might miss something useful. There is no way to match *exactly* the addresses permitted by the email RFCs with a single regex, but this should not miss too many common conventional email addresses. (Your original regex would happily accept e.g. `<` and `>` and additional `@` characters which are not permitted in unquoted email addresses.)

If you need to handle arbitrary encodings, you'll probably have to modify this. A brute-force approach would be to blindly attempt to decode the line into each possible encoding in a loop.

```py
            for enc in ('latin-1', 'utf-8', 'utf-16le', 'utf-16eb', 'gb2312', 'euc-jp'):
                try:
                    line = line.decode(enc)
                except:
                    break
                # do the regex etc
```

(Again, this smattering of encodings is completely ad hoc; I don't even remember off the top of my head what a few of these look like - maybe they are redundant for the present use case - and I'm probably missing something more or less obvious, such as a number of other Asian multibyte encodings. Latin-1 has the attractive property that it decodes every byte to the identical code point. A pure 7-bit ASCII string decodes to itself in both Latin-1 and UTF-8, so maybe only try other encodings if decoding as ASCII fails. Even then, you will get duplicates from any pure ASCII substrings with this simple snippet.)

If you know what to look for, maybe you could come up with something more sophishicated, e.g. based on patterns in some encodings (if many bytes are zeros and they occur in every other byte, that looks like UTF-16; proper UTF-8 is also easy to identify, etc).

If you don't actually know what your attempt to decode UTF-8 does, now would be a good time to finally read [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: That's almost perfect. But it return not only the email but also all other things (i mean words)that contain '@' symbol

Comment: It's not hard to construct a regex with higher precision, but probably regex is only really useful as a first-level filter. Requiring at least one dot after the `@` would probably already improve the precision drastically; `r'[-A-Za-z0-9+_.]+@[-A-Za-z0-9+]+(?:\.[-A-Za-z0-9+]+)+'` but without access to your input data it's hard to know exactly what sort of matches to expect. Again, probably add a separate filter to discard domain names which don't resolve, for example, rather than try to polish the regex.

Comment: I updated the regex in the answer; but as suggested, probably vet your data for corner cases. Technically the part before `@` can validly contain quoted strings, and e.g. unquoted `*` characters, for example; but you don't really see those in the wild. Maybe compare with the results from your original regex, though I would expect it to return a lot more junk and probably at most very few valid matches which are not captured by my attempt.